# Export CSV of a particular request in Postman using Newman

Tags: postman, export-to-csv, newman, postman-collection-runner

I have a JSON Collection of Postman requests. I am running it via Newman.
Is there a way I can export the XML Response of a particular request(Not all) to a file using newman or postman

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As I know, there is no developed XML reporter for newman.
The easiest and none-blood way to quickly resolve it this is to add response parsing to certain request or to a collection (if you need for all)

In **tests** you can add:

```
let responseJSON = JSON.parse(responseBody)
tests["Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;
if(responseCode.code !== 200)
{
    console.log(responseJSON); 
    return;
}
```

OR

```
try {
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("jwt_token", jsonData.data.token);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

OR if you don't need to output it only after an error, then put just:

```
var body = JSON.parse(responseBody)
console.log(body);
```